# Can three regular languages be concatenated?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I can't seem to find anything about this and I wonder if I'm asking a silly question.

> If you have three languages $L_1=\{a,b\}, L_2=\{c,d\}, L_3 =\{e,f\}$, can they be concatenated?

If yes, would you concatenate the first two and concatenate the result to the third one or would you concatenate it as $\{ace, ade, acf, adf, bce, \ldots\}$?
And what if one of the languages only contained the empty word $ε$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenation is associative:
$$
(L_1L_2)L_3 = L_1(L_2L_3) = \{w_1w_2w_3 : w_1 \in L_1, w_2 \in L_2, w_3 \in L_3\}.
$$
We denote the common value by $L_1L_2L_3$.

A class of languages closed under concatenation of two languages is also closed under concatenation of three or more languages, as a simple induction shows.

The "zero" element for concatenation is the empty language $\emptyset$, which satisfies $L\emptyset = \emptyset L = \emptyset$. The "one" element for concatenation is the language consisting of only the empty word $\{\epsilon\}$, which satisfies $L\{\epsilon\} = \{\epsilon\}L = L$.